# Fixing broken about:flags configuration

Tags: google-chrome

While playing around with the latest version of Google Chrome, I changed the flag in the about:flags page that enables GPU compositing on every page.  This seems to have broken Chrome for me (pages don't load at all).  This wouldn't be a huge deal, except that I'm now unable to access even the about:flags page itself.

Is there a good way to edit the flags without having access to the page (perhaps through the command line)?

The version string for my version of Chrome is: 13.0.782.10 dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable GPU composition from the command prompt by suffixing `--disable-accelerated-compositing` to Chrome shortcut.

---

Alternatively, you can open Preferences file present in `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\`, search for section pertaining to Labs experiments ( searching for `enabled_labs_experiments` should bring up the relevant section ) and edit out the parts referencing `gpu-canvas-2d`